# formatting a new json from an existing list

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my original List

```
 this.userForm.value =
[
  {
    "runid": 5,
    "partnerid":8,
    "partnername": "test admin1",
    
  },
  {
    "runid": 6,
    "partnerid": 9,
    "partnername": "test admin2",
    
  }
]
```

Need to generate a json data for save, by using value from above list. Generate a json were above partnerid mapped to adminId.

this is the required format, where patieId is a hardcoded value.

```
[
  {
    "adminId": 8,
    "patieId": 123
  },
  {
    "adminId": 9,
    "patieId": 123
  }
]
```

Tried with below code, which gives unwanted fields also.

```
 let jsonData = this.userForm.value.map(item => ({
      ...item,
      adminId:item.partnerid,
      patieId: 123, //this.patieId
        }));
```

which returns this json, here these 3 fields are not required. "runid","partnerid","partnername"

```
[
  {
    "runid": 5,
    "partnerid": 8,
    "partnername": "test admin1",
    "adminId": 8,
    "patieId": 123
  },
  {
    "runid": 6,
    "partnerid": 9,
    "partnername": "test admin2",
    "adminId": 9,
    "patieId": 123
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `...item` inserts all the fields from item, Ie the ones you don't want.

Use:

```
 let jsonData = this.userForm.value.map(item => ({
      adminId:item.partnerid,
      patieId: 123, //this.patieId
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the spread operator.

```
let jsonData = this.userForm.value.map(item => ({
      
      adminId:item.partnerid,
      patieId: 123, //this.patieId
        }));
```

You will get only {adminId: 8, patieId: 123}

Hope that's help